# The predictes push down is very important in spark, but it does not work after any map or mapPartition operatation?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to optimize the spark application. The predicates push down is very important for this. But I found that it does not work after any map or mapPartition operatation.

Anyone knows how to make spark sql predicates push down works after map or mapPartition Operation?

Answer (score 0):

Predicate Pushdown is meant for data-skipping -- it helps to reduce the amount of scanned files by eliminating files that don't contain the searched values.

This mechanism is applied only during the underlying data scan and it doesn't work against calculated columns or generated rows.

Comment: But the prediction column does not changed at all during the map or mapPartitionOperation, How to let spark know this and apply the predicate push down.

Comment: add the filter before the map/mapPartition